# Different Wi-Fi SSIDs, same network: cannot switch connections

Tags: linux, debian, networking, dhcp

I have a small network at my home, where the main Internet point stays at the living room, with two signals, a 2.4G and 5G, on the same network. Also, I have a Ethernet over Powerline link to my bedroom, with another Wi-Fi, no DHCP at this edge (serving from the main living room router).

The problem is: when connecting from Debian 9, on one network, I cannot force connection to another network, except I "forget" this connected network on my "Network Connections", on Gnome Settings.

This is really strange, because it might just work! Any clue? NetworkManager? DHCPd? The kernel itself (4.9.0-amd64 right now)?

Comment: The question is not entirely clear on what's it is happening, which limitations,  very scant on technical data and debugging

Comment: I can connect on any of three SSID's, but once connected, I cannot bind to another SSID (being on the same network+IP/subnet). I must first forget the connected SSID to connect to another one.

Comment: I more or less got that from the question. What answers are expected given the level of details of the question? Nevertheless, the Wifi protocol is not simple. Often one has to force a disconnect, and if Wifi priorities are not defined or SSIDs forgotten, it is never guaranteed which one will be picked up. If that is understood, the user will not have expectations when the protocol itself offers no guarantee.

Comment: The real deal is... why on Windows 10 everything works fine (except it keeps going here and there when the latest connected network has poor signal, but ok, it is expected...), and on Debian, it's not working? Might be some kind of "ssid+subnet binding" of NetworkManager (since this GUI/service controls all network connectivity)? Since both 3 SSID's are on the same physical network subnet?

Comment: Apples and oranges, no idea but too many variables there.